# HP Elitebook 8440p with Ubuntu 14.04: suddenly no wifi "no such device"

Tags: wireless, iwlwifi

My system is HP Elitebook 8440p. Wifi worked till yesterday but today morning I came in and noticed that wifi was not connecting, and when I tried to connect, unity desktop froze. I restarted the system and there was no wifi networks or device available.

When I typed `sudo reboot`, the system rebooted and while it was restarting it showed some text on a black screen that said something like `the wireless device is not supported. please remove it`

There is no option for wireless networks in the network manager drop down menu and there are no wifi networks.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OPXZ.jpg) of network manager menu

My system driver is iwlwifi I think. When I type `iwconfig` the following gets printed:

```
$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I'm sure there was a [wlan0] entry in that list before.

```
$ sudo ifconfig up wlan0
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
up: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:172a]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
43:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: I have seen stranger so I am going to ask the obvious. If you are using a laptop, have you tried using the F button for wireless to make sure its activated. Mine is FN+F7. Some laptops have a hard-switch you can toggle. I once reinstalled a pc because the trackpad wouldn't work and it turned out it was deactivated on the laptop itself...